# Advanced active record query, or a way to use will_paginate with an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, will-paginate

I need to use the will_paginate gem on a part of my project but as far as I can tell it only works directly on database objects. However I can't figure out this one ActiveRecord for the life of me.

I have three tables:

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :movies
  has_many :votes
end

class Movie
  has_many :votes
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The user has the ability to vote on numerous movies, and they can upload their own movie titles. I need to return the unique movie titles that the current user has voted on. It's also important to note that a user can vote on the same movie multiple times.

I can do it in straight ruby no problem :

`current_user.votes.map{|vote| vote.movie}.uniq`

But ActiveRecord is a mystery.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: * It's also important to note that a user can vote on the same movie multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each user can only vote on a given movie one time.. then since you have the associations, I would just get the user, the users votes and join in movies.

`current_user.votes.joins(:movie)`

This will provide an active record relation which can use the will_paginate methods..

`current_user.votes.joins(:movie).paginate(:page => params[:page])`

*Edit*

Since in your case a user can vote a movie multiple times, it's easier to do the query in reverse, and join the votes to the user.movies and call uniq.  Like so:

```
current_user.movies.joins(:votes).uniq
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering so quickly! So that is part of the problem, the user can vote on a movie numerous times. But I only want a listing of unique titles back.

Comment: That call will give a list of ONLY the movies that a user has voted on.  If a single user is allowed to vote on the same movie more than once, that would need to change.  Also, is it theoretically possible for you to have a movie title listed more than one time?

Comment: T movie title will only appear once. The way the app works is every time you visit the homepage 2 movie will appear at the top to be voted on. They are randomly generated, after a user votes 2 new random movies will appear. Then there is a user section where they can view all the movies they have voted on in the past. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Okay so I thought that was working. But I realized it's returning the wrong association. The problem is that a movie is owned by a user. So when you call current_user.movies it references the movies the user has uploaded, not the movies they have voted on.

Comment: That makes sense, what about grouping it by the movie id, so you'd only get one record.  LIke `current_user.votes.joins(:movie).group('movies.id')`